# How to not compile the bibliography everytime in TexStudio using BibTex

Tags: bibtex, compiling, texstudio

In TexStudios the bibliography is automatically compiled every time I compile, hence slowing down compilation time several-fold (by compiling four times).

Can I disable automatic bibliography compilation so that I can speed up compilation time?

Comment: You just have to choose you compilation sequence. See [Texstudio manual section1.3 Configuring the build system](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html)

Comment: You may also want to look into tools like `latexmk` or `arara`. `latexmk` uses a heuristic approach to find out what programmes need to be run, so BibTeX will only be run if necessary. `arara` lets you define complex custom rules for document compilation.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Tools* menu , you have the *Commands* submenu, which offers the choice between LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, bibtex, biber, &c. You can define a shortcut for the compiler you want to use:

[image]